# Find general and parametric equations of the plane containing the points $A(3, 0, 0), B(0, 1, 0)$ 'perpendicular' to the $XY-$plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry, plane-geometry

**Question :** Find general and parametric equations of the plane containing the points $A(3, 0, 0), B(0, 1, 0)$ 'perpendicular' to the $XY-$plane.

**My Try :** Seeing that the plane is perpendicular to the $XY-$plane and contains the point $A(3,0,0)$, I tried inserting a point $C(3,0,3)$ as it would be directly above A and perfectly perpendicular to $AB$. Say $AB=u$ and $AC=v$. I cross $u$ and $v$ $(u \times v)$ and it gives me the vector that ought to be perpendicular to the plane $n=(1,3,0)$.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to MSE! It's common courtesy here to add what you've already tried and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've shown a bit of the work you've done yourself. Good luck!

Comment: @Geigercounter Thank you for the tip!

 seeing that the plane is perpendicular to the XY plane and contains the point A(3,0,0) , I tried inserting a point C(3,0,3) as it would be directly above A and perfectly perpendicular to AB. say AB=u and AC=v. I cross u and v (u x v) and it gives me the vector that ought to be perpendicular to the plane n=(1,3,0). This is where I'm stuck at.

Comment: @Geigercounter Permission to copy your comment as a template message?

Comment: @ryang sure no problem!